# SQL UPDATE CASE returns (0 rows affected), it shouldn't

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run an SQL command like this

```
UPDATE Category
SET SortOrder = (
        CASE 
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name1' THEN 1
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name2' THEN 2 
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name3' THEN 3 
        END
    )
WHERE Deleted = 0 AND Name IN ('[name1,name2,name3]')
```

But it returns (0 rows affected). But when i check their values it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE Deleted = 0 AND Name IN ('[name1,name2,name3]')
```

This matches exactly one string . . . `'[name1,name2,name3]'`.

If you want to match different values, you want:

```
WHERE Deleted = 0 AND Name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
```

Answer (score 2):

remove [ ] and use separate string inside `in`

```
UPDATE Category
SET SortOrder = 
        CASE 
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name1' THEN 1
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name2' THEN 2 
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name3' THEN 3 
        END

WHERE Deleted = 0 AND Name IN ('name1','name2','name3')
```

value of name will be separate string

Comment: Yeah i tried that, get same result :/

Comment: @Charlie answer edited your name value will be separete string

Comment: @Charlie does it works

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
UPDATE Category
SET SortOrder = (
        CASE 
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name1' THEN 1
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name2' THEN 2 
            WHEN Category.Name = 'name3' THEN 3 
        END
    )
WHERE Deleted = 0 AND Category.Name IN ('name1','name2','name3')
```